# Merge HEX file into existing ELF file in ghidra

Tags: ghidra, elf, hex

I have an Infineon Tricore **ELF** file. I have a **HEX** file that has been patched with minor changes and new code appended (e.g. the hex from the ELF was exported and then had changes made to it manually effectively via a hex editor).

How can I "**replace**" the hex within the ELF file but not lose all the other metadata in the elf file for processing?

Is there any way to import a HEX into an existing ELF project and have it override the binary it has already extracted?

I'm sure a tool could be written to do this, I'm just trying to save time and see if there is any existing functionality to do this. I am fairly inexperienced with **Ghidra**.

The goal is to get all the function names/variables annotated in the new modified HEX file.